# Can I migrate a library from SP 2016 down to a different SP 2013 farm?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, library, migrate

Can I migrate a SP library (of documents) from SharePoint 2016 down to a new SharePoint 2013 farm/ site?

We just want this content and folder structure on the SP 2013 farm (Not the entire site collection).

Is this possible?
Is it difficult?
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to use a 3rd party content migration tool. One such example is Sharegate.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve just tested with **list template** (include contents) and move the copy of the template from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint 2013, which is definitely not a recommended solution in this scenario, but it worked.

The library displayed a *Web Part Error* in SP13 when I created a new document library using that template. Then I edited the page and re-added the Document Library web part, the issue got solved and the library is in well function.